# Second featured image WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve on a page the second featured image of a post. I couldn't find any reference about that. Any help on how to do it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reference to add a second featured image to the post. I have used this plugin multiples times. It's working for me.

https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/#installation

Once you install the plugin , add this code to your template.

```html
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Secondary Image',
            'id' => 'secondary-image',
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for that. Unfortunately this snippet is not displaying the second featured image. Do I have to add any statement in the function.php?

Comment: Hi , You have to install the Plugin Multiple Post Thumbnails and then add the snippet. This the link https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/ and this the documentation https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki Ed.